# $\int_{\mathbf{R}} F^n(ax)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ with $a>0$ and $f=F^\prime$

Tags: improper-integrals

Fix an integer $n\ge 2$ and let $f: \mathbf{R}\to [0,\infty)$ be a density function, that is, a continuous function such that $\int_{\mathbf{R}}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=1$.

In addition, for each $x \in \mathbf{R}$, set $F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t$.

> **Question.** Is it possible to evaluate / provide a "sufficiently good approximation" of the integral
>   $$
> \int_{\mathbf{R}} F^n(ax)f(x)\mathrm{d}x,
> $$
>   where $a$ is a fixed positive constant?

Comment: Not in general - it really depends on the specific function $f.$

Comment: I am not sure, but is it legit to write it as $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} F^n(ax)dF$$ and use integration by parts?